# How to create a sql script that get distinct entry?

Tags: sql

[image]

I have a picture as above, I would like to keep the item 2 and item 4 that have max count and name duplicated, but I need to keep the ID column. how to write the SQL script and get the result as below?

```
ID  Name    Count
2   A   5
4   B   5
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer may depend on the product used.)

Comment: @jarlh All you really should need is max() which is pretty standard.  Well, depends how you do it, of course...  :)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this is what you want:

```
SELECT id, name, count
  FROM my_table mt1
 WHERE count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM my_table mt2 WHERE mt1.name = mt2.name);
```

**EDIT:** If, however, as Chris suggests it does have duplicates:

```
SELECT MAX(id), name, count
  FROM my_table mt1
 WHERE count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM my_table mt2 WHERE mt1.name = mt2.name)
GROUP BY name, count;
```

Output is:

```
+------+------+-------+
| id   | name | count |
+------+------+-------+
|    2 | A    |     5 |
|    4 | B    |     5 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: This will work for the data shown but if there are two rows with the same max Count it will select them both.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Count
FROM myTable
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable t2
  WHERE t2.Name = myTable.Name
  AND (t2.Count > myTable.Count
  OR (t2.Count = myTable.Count AND t2.ID > myTable.ID))) = 0;
```

Comment: Okay, so yours returns duplicates too, by the way. :)  But other than that it works.

Comment: Yeah, if there are two rows with the max count, there will still be no rows with a greater count so both will be returned.

Comment: Almost there.  I think your last line needs to be "AND ( **(** t2.ID > myTable.ID **AND t2.Count = myTable.Count)** OR t2.Count > myTable.Count)) = 0;" Otherwise it will toss entries when there is a higher id but a lower count.

Comment: @D.L. Doh! Thanks.... I must have been having an off-day or something. Amended accordingly.